# why is my textalign not editable?

Tags: javascript, canvas, text-alignment

Heyy guys,

I am trying to make a sort of a game. Butt it is not going very well..

If you look at the piece of my game below and run it you will see red and green objects in the top. After these objects are numbers like: 200/200. The hole top is placed under `legenda.draw()`

What I want is `textAlign = "initial"` just the default for these numbers.

But if you look at the red square with "klaar", I want that one the `textAlign = "center"`. The square is placed under `koopscherm.draw()`.

Now you know what I want I can tell you my problem. When I run the script all the text is centered. And I want just the square to be centererd ( <-- don`t know how to write).

I found out that if I first run `legenda.draw()` and then `koopscherm.draw()` the problem is fixed. But for my game it is important to first run `koopscherm.draw()`.

Sooo.. I want to have the text for `koopscherm.draw()` in the center and for `legenda.draw()` as default.

Thnx for all your help!

```
<head>

<style>
    body{
        background-color:white;
    }
    * {cursor: none;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<script>
    function Canvas(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('game').getContext('2d');
        var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
        var ch = ctx.canvas.height;

        var keys = [];

        var cursor = new Image();
        cursor.src = "nothing"

        function legenda(){
            this.x = 10, this.y = 10, this.w = 160, this.h = 23, this.color = "black", this.max = cw*0.125, this.geld = 0;
            this.x2 = cw*0.6, this.y2 = 10, this.w2 = 160, this.h2 = 23, this.color2 = "black", this.alle_lv = 200, this.aantal_lv = this.alle_lv;
            this.w3 = cw, this.h3 = ch*0.1, this.x3 = 0, this.y3 = 0, this.color3 = "lightgray", this.trans3 = 0.5;
            this.st_w = 0, this.st_h = this.h/1.1, this.st_x = this.x + (this.x-(this.x/1.1)), this.st_y = this.y + (this.y-(this.y/1.1)), this.st_color = "red";
            this.st_w2 = 0, this.st_h2 = this.h2/1.1, this.st_x2 = this.x2 + (this.x2-(this.x2/1.0025)), this.st_y2 = this.y2 + (this.y2-(this.y2/1.1)), this.st_color2 = "#33CC33";
            this.const_plus = 7/100, this.const = this.w*0.99/7, this.const2 = this.w2*0.99/200;
            this.draw = function(){
                //menu balk
                ctx.globalAlpha = this.trans3
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color3;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x3,this.y3,this.w3,this.h3);

                //check
                ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

                // magazijn
                    //zwarte achtergrond
                    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);

                    //aantal magazijn
                    this.st_w = 0;
                    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
                        this.st_w+=this.const
                    }

                    ctx.fillStyle = this.st_color;
                    ctx.fillRect(this.st_x,this.st_y,this.st_w,this.st_h);

                    //magazijn in nummers
                    ctx.font="17px Arial";
                    ctx.textBaseline="middle";
                    ctx.textAlign = "initial";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    var text = Math.round(7)+" / "+7;
                    ctx.fillText(text,this.x+this.w+7.5,this.y+this.h*0.5,this.max);


                // levens van het fort
                    //zwarte achtergrond
                    ctx.fillStyle = this.color2;
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x2,this.y2,this.w2,this.h2);

                    //stukjes2
                    this.st_w2 = 0;
                    for(var i=0;i<200;i++){
                        this.st_w2+=this.const2
                    }

                    ctx.fillStyle = this.st_color2;
                    ctx.fillRect(this.st_x2,this.st_y2,this.st_w2,this.st_h2);

                    //levens in nummers
                    ctx.font="17px Arial";
                    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
                    ctx.textAlign = "initial";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    var text = Math.round(200)+" / "+200;
                    ctx.fillText(text,this.x2+this.w2+7.5,this.y2+this.h2*0.5,this.max);


                // geld
                    //geld in nummers
                    ctx.font="17px Arial";
                    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
                    ctx.textAlign = "center"
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    var text = "\u20AC"+this.geld;
                    ctx.fillText(text,cw*0.48,this.y2+this.h2*0.5,cw*0.12);
            }
        }


        function koopscherm(){
            this.tekst = [({"text":"Klaar","font":"17px Arial","Baseline":"middle","textAlign":"center","color":"black","x":cw*0.03+(cw*0.45*0.5),"y":ch*0.88+(ch*0.08*0.5),"max":cw*0.45})];
            this.vierkanten = [
                               {"x":cw*0.03,"y":ch*0.88,"w":cw*0.45,"h":ch*0.08,"color":"lightgray"}
                              ];
            this.draw = function(){
                //draw
                for(var i=0;i<this.vierkanten.length;i++){
                    var v = this.vierkanten[i];
                    ctx.fillStyle = v.color;
                    ctx.fillRect(v.x,v.y,v.w,v.h);
                }
                for(var i=0;i<this.tekst.length;i++){
                    var v = this.tekst[i];
                    ctx.font = v.font;
                    ctx.textBaseline = v.Baseline;
                    ctx.textAlign = v.textAlign;
                    ctx.fillStyle = v.color;
                    ctx.fillText(v.text,v.x,v.y,v.max);
                }
                //check
                ctx.textAlign = "initial";

                //muis
                //ctx.drawImage(cursor,this.x2,this.y2,12,22);
            }
        }

        var legenda = new legenda();
        var koopscherm = new koopscherm();

        function draw() {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

            //draw

            koopscherm.draw();
            legenda.draw();

            ctx.restore();
        }

        var animateInterval = setInterval(draw,1);

        ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            koopscherm.dx = event.clientX;
            koopscherm.dy = event.clientY;
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
            Canvas();
    });
</script>

<div id="center_canvas">
<canvas id="game" width="650px" height="450px">
    Je hebt een nieuwere browser nodig om dit te spelen!
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value for `textAlign` is `start` (there is no `initial`). A value that isn't recognized is simply [ignored](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#text-styles) (my emphasis):

> The textAlign IDL attribute, on getting, must return the current
>   value. On setting, if the value is one of start, end, left, right, or
>   center, then the value must be changed to the new value. **Otherwise,
>   the new value must be ignored.**

Hope this helps.